# How to change a multidimension array element with a function

Tags: php, arrays, function, multidimensional-array

I have an array like this:

```
<?php
$arr = [
    'a' => [
        'a1' => [
            'A11', 'A12', 'A13'
        ]
    ]
];
```

I can change the `A13` element in an easy way:

```
$arr['a']['a1'][2] = 'A13 NEW';
```

But I want to do this with a function, something like this:

```
f($arr, ['a', 'a1', 2], 'A13 New');
```

I write this function using `eval` and I don't like it.

```
<?php
function f(&$array, $index, $value) {
    $e = '$array';
    for ($i = 0, $l = count($index); $i < $l; $i++) {
        $e .= '[$index[' . $i . ']]';
    }
    $e .= ' = $value;';

    // now we have `$e` like this
    // $array[$index[0]][$index[1]][$index[2]] = $value;

    eval($e);
}
```

How can I write this function without using `eval`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$arr = array(
    'a' => array(
        'a1' => array(
            'A11', 'A12', 'A13'
        )
    )
);

function f(&$arr, $index, $value) {
    $tmp = &$arr;
    foreach ($index as $key) {
        $tmp = &$tmp[$key];
    }
    $tmp = $value;
}

f($arr, array('a', 'a1', 2), 'A13 New');

//$arr['a']['a1'][2] = 'A13 NEW';
var_dump($arr);
```